# alignment of images

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, flexbox

Возникло затруднение, как правильней расположить левую часть, где расположены 2 изображения, так чтобы выглядело прилично на всех разрешениях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.image-container {
  height: 290px;
  width: 290px;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 142.5px 0px rgba(60, 103, 176, 0.40);
}

.image-right{
  top: 80px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.left-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: left, right !important;
  .docs-block {
    margin-top: 256px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-03">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left-block col-xl-6 section-overlay">
                <div class="docs-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="image-container image-left"
                                 style="background-image: url('assets/img/Слой 6.png')">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="image-container image-right"
                                 style="background-image: url('assets/img/Слой 7.png')">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-block col-xl-6">
                <div class="education-info"></div>
                <div class="blue-block"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Думал, может лучше использовать position:absolute для их расположения, но пока не придумал как это сделать.

Надеюсь на помощь) От вас.

Comment: А картинки должны менять размер, или ширина и высота фиксированная?

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так

```css
.one,.two{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: silver;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.two{
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div> 
<div class="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У блока, оборачивающего картинку нужно проставить vertical-align в css, для меня это новость буквально вчерашнего дня, но картинки чувствительны к этому параметру. Просто проставь внешнему блоку этот параметр, и все само собой решится